# ObjectDisposedException on AWS ListBuckets call in Unity3D

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make use of the AWS .NET SDK in a Unity3D game. I've taken the 3.5 dll and I'm using that in my project. To test it's all working correctly I'm just attempting to list all of the buckets available, I've checked using Cloudberry that all the credentials and permissions are correct so that shouldn't be a problem.

The exception being thrown:

> ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed.
>   System.Net.HttpWebResponse.CheckDisposed ()
>   System.Net.HttpWebResponse.GetResponseHeader (System.String headerName)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.HttpWebResponse:GetResponseHeader (string)
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.HttpWebRequestResponseData.GetHeaderValue (System.String name)
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.HasSSEHeaders (IWebResponseData webResponseData)
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.ProcessResponseHandlers (IExecutionContext executionContext)
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.PostInvoke (IExecutionContext executionContext)
>   Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeSync (IExecutionContext executionContext)
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync (IExecutionContext executionContext)
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync (IExecutionContext executionContext)
>   UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()

After stepping through the code, the error seems to appear on the line which reads `var res = client.ListBuckets();`. Here's the code that's being used.

```
public class FileStorage
{
    private const string accessKey = @"access_key";
    private const string secretKey = @"secret_key";
    private const string bucketName = @"bucket_name";

    private AmazonS3Client client;
    private AmazonS3Config config;

    public FileStorage()
    {
        config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            ServiceURL = "http://s3.amazonaws.com"
        };
    }

    public void ListBuckets()
    {
        var client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, config);
        var res = client.ListBuckets();
        foreach (S3Bucket b in res.Buckets)
        {
            Debug.Log(b.BucketName);
        }
    }
}
```

I've taken out this class and put it into a visual studio project that's running .NET 3.5 to test it out and it works perfectly fine and lists all of the buckets that I'd expect.

The error feels rather unhelpful so I'm not sure if this is a problem with the library and Unity or something I'm doing wrong with my code. What could be causing this, or does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: So we never figured out the answer, in the end we whipped up a quick web service to act as a middleman for AWS for us, this is what we wanted for the final version but during the prototype we just wanted to do it quickly and directly to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted the exact same thing and ran into the same problem.

This is not perfect but here's the workaround:

Checkout `https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net`

You have to patch

```
  Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller
      private void Unmarshall(IExecutionContext executionContext)
```

The HttpsResponse is disposed in the finally block. If you just comment this out you are back in business.

I assume it's a problem with the old mono runtime but I also could not understand why this could ever work. But since I only want this to work ... :-) Also the GC will clean the response objects so you will not even get into trouble.

BTW: This is actually *really* easy to do. Just checkout the project. Open the 3.5 version. Build worked instantly for me. So this will take about 10 minutes to do.

Comment: I also submitted a ticket so maybe amazon provides a fix: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/261

Comment: Interesting workaround, would be good to know if amazon find an actual problem but I do feel it's a bit of a bug. I'll mark your answer as correct for anyone else that needs it in the future but I changed my approach in the end.